# Trying to create a json but i get a php warning

Tags: php, arrays, json

When I run this:

```
  <?php    
    $array = array_count_values($roles);
    var_dump($roles);
    $result = array();
    foreach($array as $key => $value) {
          $result[]=array("name"=>$key,"data"=>$value);
    } 
  ?>
```

I get this

> Warning: array_count_values(): Can only count STRING and INTEGER
>   values!

The `var_dump` gives me

```
array(7) { ["francese"]=> array(2) { ["maschio"]=> array(1) { [0]=> bool(true) } ["femmina"]=> array(1) { [0]=> bool(true) } } ["chimica"]=> array(1) { ["maschio"]=> array(2) { [0]=> bool(true) [1]=> bool(true) } } ["fisica"]=> array(2) { ["maschio"]=> array(2) { [0]=> bool(true) [1]=> bool(true) } ["femmina"]=> array(1) { [0]=> bool(true) } } ["scienze"]=> array(1) { ["maschio"]=> array(1) { [0]=> bool(true) } } ["inglese"]=> array(1) { ["maschio"]=> array(1) { [0]=> bool(true) } } ["spagnolo"]=> array(1) { ["maschio"]=> array(1) { [0]=> bool(true) } } ["italiano"]=> array(1) { ["femmina"]=> array(1) { [0]=> bool(true) } } }
```

When I run this I get the correct result:

```
    <?php
      foreach($roles as $skill => $genderB) {
        $males = isset($genderB['maschio']) ? count($genderB['maschio']): 0;
        $females = isset($genderB['femmina']) ? count($genderB['femmina']): 0;
        $total = $males + $females;
        $data[] = $total;
        echo "<li>We have ".$total." teachers of ".$skill.", ".$males." male, ".$females." female</li>";
      }
    ?>
```

Result

```
We have 2 teachers of francese, 1 male, 1 female 
We have 2 teachers of chimica, 2 male, 0 male
```

And what I would like to achieve is:

```
[{"name":"francese","data":2},{"name":"inglese","data":4}]
```

I am getting confused on which array I should be getting

**UPDATE**

This is the `json_encode($roles)` as request in the comment

```
{"francese":{"maschio":[true],"femmina":[true]},"chimica":{"maschio":[true,true]},"fisica":{"maschio":[true,true],"femmina":[true]},"scienze":{"maschio":[true]},"inglese":{"maschio":[true]},"spagnolo":{"maschio":[true]},"italiano":{"femmina":[true]}}
```

**UPDATE 2**

With the answer I got I am still not getting the correct json

```
 [{"name":0,"data":{"name":"francese","data":2}},{"name":1,"d‌​ata":{"name":"chimic‌​a","data":2}},{"name‌​":2,"data":{"name":"‌​fisica","data":3}},{‌​"name":3,"data":{"na‌​me":"scienze","data"‌​:1}},{"name":4,"data‌​":{"name":"inglese",‌​"data":1}},{"name":5‌​,"data":{"name":"spa‌​gnolo","data":1}},{"‌​name":6,"data":{"nam‌​e":"italiano","data"‌​:1}}]
```

when I run

```
$result = array(); 
foreach($final_array as $key => $value) { 
  $result[]=array("name"=>$key,"data"=>$value); 
}
echo json_encode($result);
```

It should be

> [{"name":"francese","data":2},{"name":"inglese","data":4}]

Comment: Can you provide `json_encode($roles)` so that we can better help you out

Comment: @SahilGulati sure, just updated the question with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just need to make array and push it into final array like otherwise your code perfect

```
// $data[] = $total;
 $final_array[]=array("name"=>$skill,"data"=>$total);
```

**UPDATE 1:**

```
 <?php
 $roles ='{"francese":{"maschio":[true],"femmina":[true]},"chimica":{"maschio":[true,true]},"fisica":{"maschio":[true,true],"femmina":[true]},"scienze":{"maschio":[true]},"inglese":{"maschio":[true]},"spagnolo":{"maschio":[true]},"italiano":{"femmina":[true]}}';


    $roles_new = json_decode($roles,true);

    echo "<pre>";

    print_r($roles_new);

    $final_array =array();
    foreach($roles as $skill => $genderB) {
    $males = isset($genderB['maschio']) ? count($genderB['maschio']): 0;
    $females = isset($genderB['femmina']) ? count($genderB['femmina']): 0;
    $total = $males + $females;
    $final_array[]=array("name"=>$skill,"data"=>$total);
    }

    print_r($final_array);

    echo json_encode($final_array);

    ?>
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
[{"name":"francese","data":2},{"name":"chimica","data":2},{"name":"fisica","data":3},{"name":"scienze","data":1},{"name":"inglese","data":1},{"name":"spagnolo","data":1},{"name":"italiano","data":1}]
```

Comment: if I run this         
`$array = array_count_values($final_array);
        $result = array();
        foreach($array as $key => $value) {
              $result[]=array("name"=>$key,"data"=>$value);
        } 
      ?>` I get `Warning: array_count_values(): Can only count STRING and INTEGER values!`

Comment: remove this line $array = array_count_values($roles);

Comment: yeah but if i remove that how do I access $final_array?

Comment: yes ok i got that but I need to run the first function as per the question, the very first I wrote at the top, because that will produce me basically the json i need for the chart i'm building

Comment: this is the json encode of `[{"name":0,"data":{"name":"francese","data":2}},{"name":1,"data":{"name":"chimica","data":2}},{"name":2,"data":{"name":"fisica","data":3}},{"name":3,"data":{"name":"scienze","data":1}},{"name":4,"data":{"name":"inglese","data":1}},{"name":5,"data":{"name":"spagnolo","data":1}},{"name":6,"data":{"name":"italiano","data":1}}]` when I run  `$result = array();
        foreach($final_array as $key => $value) {
              $result[]=array("name"=>$key,"data"=>$value);
        }`

Comment: and that isn't like i need it as state din the question the correct format would have to be `[{"name":"francese","data":2},{"name":"inglese","data":4}]`

Comment: i think you doing with wrong variable check my full code it gives output as your expected output @RobertoMarras

Comment: this is how i got it right `$result = array();
        foreach($final_array as $key => $value) { 
          $result[]= $value;
        } echo json_encode($result);`

Comment: inside the loop $value is array() you need to extract the value from it instead of pushing the same array into $result[] =array();

Comment: could you update your answer with the code you think i should be using? because it is working with what i gave you in the comment just before, is it wrong? if so could you please provide it in an update? thanks